# Python: how to remove the first two words in a string which changes in amount of words?

Tags: python

I want to remove the first two words from a string that has a changing amount of words (it's a user input) I'm not sure how to go about doing this, any suggestions would help!

Comment: 1. your question statement is quite confusing. 2. we don't know what kind of input would you expect, any sample input? 3. what would be the sample output? 4. have you tried anything yourself? 5. if yes, are you having some kind of trouble solving it? 6. what trouble? 7. any error logs or anything? 8. have you searched the internet for the solution? 9. what answers did you get out there? 10. how aren't they helpful?

Answer (score 4):

```
s = 'some long string with random number of words'
remove_first_2 = ' '.join(s.split()[2:])
```

- `s.split()` splits string into list. default delimiter is whitespace-sequence.
- `[2:]` take that list, from the 3rd element on
- `' '.join` make a string from it, seperating each element with `' '`

Comment: Nice! it worked! care to explain what I'm looking at here? what's the 2:?